# Wpf contentControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, contentcontrol

New programmer question:

I'm trying to create a simple navigation welcome page similiar to wht you whould see on an ipad.

My MainWindow has a titlebar (which wont change) and the rest will be a container of sorts that will show differnt things based on events.

So here is my question how do I bind the container (contentcontrol) to show other views ie show welcomeview originally and then if a user click on a button from the welcome view the content control shows the view they selected.

I currently has the Welcome Page as:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControl.Views.WelcomeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentControl.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:WelcomeViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Background="red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White">
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" Content="DASH" Command="{Binding ViewChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="Dashboard"/>
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" Content="ROOM" Command="{Binding ViewChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="MeetingRoom"/>
        <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="5" Content="SCREEN" Command="{Binding ViewChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="Screen" />
    </DockPanel>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Blue"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The viewModel is as follows:

```
class WelcomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private MainWindowViewModel _mainWindowVm;
    private RelayCommand<string> _viewChangedCommand;

    public ICommand ViewChangedCommand
    {
        get { return _viewChangedCommand ?? (_viewChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnViewChanged)); }
    }


    public event EventHandler ViewChanged;

    private void OnViewChanged(string view)
    {
        EventHandler handler = ViewChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(view, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel MainWindowVm
    {
        get { return _mainWindowVm; }
        set
        {
            _mainWindowVm = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MainViewModel");
        }
    }

    public WelcomeViewModel()
    {
        MainWindowVm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        ViewChanged += MainWindowVm.ViewChanged;
    }
}
}
```

And I have my Mainwindow as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="ContentControl.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContentControl.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ContentControl.Views"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ScreenViewModel}">
        <views:ScreenView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WelcomeViewModel}">
        <views:WelcomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MeetingRoomViewModel}">
        <views:MeetingRoomView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
        <views:DashboardView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>This Is My Label</Label>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainPanel" Content="{Binding Content, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            MinHeight="200"
            MinWidth="200"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Focusable="False">
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Main Window View Model:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private UserControl _content;

    public UserControl Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Content");
        }
    }



    public void ViewChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (o.ToString())
        {
            case "Welcome":
                {
                    var welcome = new WelcomeView();
                   Content = welcome;
                    break;
                }
            case "MeetingRoom":
                {
                    var meetingRoom = new MeetingRoomView();
                    Content= meetingRoom;
                    break;
                }
            case "Dashboard":
                {
                    var dashboard = new DashboardView();
                    Content = dashboard;
                    break;
                }
            case "Screen":
                {
                    var screen = new ScreenView();
                    Content = screen;
                    break;
                }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(o.ToString());
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()

    {

    }

}
}
```

How do I hook these Up to work with each other So I can show the WelcomeView as the content of the contentcontrol and then when I press a button have the ContentControl change to what was selected.

Again sorry I am new to MVVM and WPF and these binding are messing with my head.

Answer (score 1):

The Buttons DASH, ROOM, SCREEN, should be on the MainWindow. The ViewChangedCommand should be on the MainWindowViewModel. And the content will be showed by dynamic templating.

If you want the buttons on the controls:
Ok so, then let's put the buttons on the controls, but the change content command should be in the MainWindowViewModel. To make a binding like this you should do something like this:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ChangeContentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

in your buttons

Comment: I don't want them on the main Window I want to be able to load the controls from each view and be able to use them within the mainwindow I don't want the main window to have any buttons on it. The buttons with be only on the views loaded from the contentcontrol

Comment: Ok so, then let's put the buttons on the controls, but the change content command should be in the MainWindowViewModel. To make a binding like this you should do something like this

Comment: But i think that this could have some redundant code. You may have blogal buttons on the main window, and also, the controls could define theirs own buttons

Comment: I'm sorry I am New, this isn't making sence I don't know what you asking me to change

Comment: You have the ViewChangedCommand in your WelcomeViewModel, and should be in your MainWindowViewModel, then the buttons in your control should have the Binding like a said abouve. It is clear now? Please tell if is not.

Comment: It can't go in the MainWindow View model or the buttons wont call it when slected

Comment: The binding that i wrote dosent work? Did you set the MainWindow.DataContext  = new MainWindowViewModel()?